# Unsure how to fix li item widths

Tags: html, css

I am pretty new to css and html and I am trying to create a drop-down menu that has 3 or 4 columns of links per drop down.  I want the columns to be inline with each other.  I have managed to accomplish that but the links in each column are going on two or more lines and I'd like them to display on one.

I've been messing around with the css but can't seem to figure out how to make them display on one line per link.

In my codpen, you will see what I am working with: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLQGqM

The best I've been able to do is make

```css
.tlgnav .tlgnav-column {
 
 width: 100%;
  }
```

, but this makes the columns stack on top of each other, which is not what I want.

I am thinking it might have something to do with my .tlgnav li being set at width of 16.66% but if I change that, my menu doesn't fill the width of the screen.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I'll remember that for the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `white-space : nowrap` to avoid the line breaking, but maybe it's a better way to doing this. I answer with this solution but if someone gets something better follow it.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjGzgZ

```
.tlgnav h3 + ul li {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I don't really care how it works, just glad there is an option.

Comment: It works making no line break, it avoid line break because a whitespace. More info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space